# How to consume a JSON endpoint?

Tags: javascript, java, c#, json, web-services

So I have been supplied an URL for an `"exposed JSON endpoint"` similar to one found [**here**](http://orc.csres.utexas.edu/orchard/json/compiler)-only difference is the functions are different. First of all what does this mean("exposed JSON endpoint") ? And how do I call this web service ? I have used web services like the Google Maps with C# where I would download and parse the XML from URL and use the data. But with this, I have no idea how to use the service.  (any code in Javascript, C#, Java is fine). Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 2):

An "exposed JSON endpoint" is a publicly available URL (sometimes with query or path parameters added by you) which you can send an HTTP request to and it will return JSON from the remote server that is related to the request you sent.

You then parse the returned JSON (into the structure of whatever programming language you are using) so you can then use the returned data in your own code.

Comment: How can I call this service ? It doesn't have any instructions !

Comment: @JennaMaiz - that depends upon your programming environment.  Most environments will have a mechanism/library for making an HTTP request.  That's what you would use.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I am specifically asking about the CompilerService JSON service link I provided ?

Comment: @JennaMaiz - that link is for making requests of that service from browser Javascript.  I thought you were asking about making requests from C# or Java or something other than a browser. An HTTP request is a specific networking operation that is language independent.  How to make an HTTP request in a given language depends upon the tools offered in that language, so that can be answered only within the context of a specific language and programming environment.

Comment: I guess I am not following. Can you point me to any documentation on this ? What is meant by "browser javascript" ?

Comment: @JennaMaiz - "browser Javsascript" is Javascript running in a web page loaded into a browser.

Comment: @JennaMaiz - that pages shows you exactly how to make a request in a browser web page.  It's fully documented there.  I thought you were asking how to make such a request outside of a web page (like from your own custom programmed application).  So, now it's not clear at all what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Oh I see. I see you have lot experience with Javascript, so would you mind telling me how to create a sample request with it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91685/discussion-between-jenna-maiz-and-jfriend00).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead("Endpoint");
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
```

Comment: How does this call the specific "compile" service from the endpoint ?

Answer (score 1):

As the service end point states:

You need to include the following element in your page

```
<script src="http://orc.csres.utexas.edu/orchard/json/compiler?js"/></script>
```

Then you call the service using something like this

```
try {

compilerService.compile(
    {
        devKey : "key", 
        program : "program"
    },
    function(returnValue) { 
        // it worked do something with returnValue
        console.log(returnValue); 
    },
    function(response, status, exception) {
        // something went wrong
        console.log(response);
        console.log(status);
        console.log(exception);
    }
);

}
catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: How would I modify the code to include basic authentication ?

Comment: That's a whole different problem; essentially the 'generated' code from the endpoint (the bit referenced in the `<script>` tag) would have to expose something on the `compile` method for you to pass a username/password to. You could modify the code yourself, save the following JS http://orc.csres.utexas.edu/orchard/json/compiler?js to your application, then modify the `XmlHttpRequest` portion to allow basic auth.